# SwiperJS version 11 gives me a weird warning

Tags: swiper.js

Im getting a weird warning in swiperJS@11

```
Swiper Loop Warning: The number of slides is not enough for loop mode, 
it will be disabled and not function properly. You need to add more slides 
(or make duplicates) or lower the values of slidesPerView and slidesPerGroup parameters
```

The code is playing nicely with no problems. Same code when using swiperjs@9 disappears. Does anyone knows, why is this happening?

I have 8 slides and Im still getting the loop warning. Also I've checked:

- Ensure Enough Slides
- Check for Duplicate Slides
- Verified Initialization Timing

my code:

```
this.swiper = new Swiper( this.$refs.mySwiper, {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
console.log('Number of slides:', this.swiper.slides.length);
// Number of slides: 8
```